# Lightswitch 2013 - passing a parameter to a details picker on load

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

What I am trying to do is add an item to an order. and I want it to pass the OrderID from the previous screen to the new screen (which I have achieved and you can see below) however the user still has to press the + arrow on the details picker and select it. I want to remove this and just do it automatically... any tips:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could query the database in the screen created method for the order that is passed in when the screen is shown.

```
myapp.AddEditEquipment.created = function (screen) {
    //Whatever other initializing you have to do
    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Equipment_SingleOrDefault(screen.OrderIDPass)
        .execute().then(function (result) {
            screen.OrderRequest = result;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the beforeShown option of the ShowAddEditEquipment method. It looks like you're already launching the screen manually via a method in your Browse screen.

```
myapp.showAddEditEquipment(OrderID);
```

Or something like that. You'll want to change it to:

```
myapp.showAddEditEquipment(null, {
    beforeShown: function (addEditScreen) {
        addEditScreen.Order = screen.Order;
    }
});
```

This is a bit vague, if you could post some of your code, I could modify this to match your code more exactly.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I deleted all the attempts as I was going along so I don't actually have any.. the above statement im a little confused in the (addEditScreen) within the brackets, should this be linked or is it just a deceleration or is this linked with the screen I am passing the parameter from? cheers pal

Comment: I'm not entirely sure myself how that works. I think it links itself to the screen in question. The name is purely arbitrary.